# For any $S \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, if $\partial S$ denotes the boundary of $S$, prove that $\partial(\partial S) \subseteq \partial S$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I am self-learning Real Analysis from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbott. I learnt the trick of constructing a $\delta$-neighborhood of a random point $y \in (x - \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ to always reside in this $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$.

I tried to write a proof for the below assertion, and would like to ask if my proof checks out.

> For any $S \subseteq \mathbf{R}$, if $\partial S$ denotes the boundary of $S$, prove that $\partial(\partial S) \subseteq \partial S$.

***My Attempt***.

Let $x$ be an element of $\partial(\partial S)$.

By definition of the boundary of a set $S$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, the open interval $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ contains at least one element of $\partial S$ and at least one element of $(\partial S)^C$.

We are interested to prove that, $\forall \epsilon>0$, the open interval $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ contains at least one element of $S$ and at least one element of $S^C$.

Pick an arbitrary element $y \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$, such that $y \in \partial S$. Then, for every $\delta > 0$, the open interval $(y - \delta, y + \delta)$ contains atleast one element of $S$ and atleast one element of $S^C$. If we choose,
\begin{align*}
\delta = \delta_0 = \min \left\{\frac{y - (x-\epsilon)}{2},\frac{(x + \epsilon) - y}{2}\right\}
\end{align*}

Then, $(y - \delta_0,y + \delta_0) \subseteq (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$.

So, we found a small $\delta_0$-neighborhood, $(y - \delta_0,y + \delta_0)$ inside of $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$, which contains at least one element of $S$ and at least one element of $S^C$, for all $\epsilon>0$.

Consequently, we have shown that, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ contains at least one element of $S$ and at least one element of $S^C$.

So, $x \in \partial S$.

Hence, $\partial(\partial S) \subseteq \partial S$. This closes the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did looks good to me.

**Below another proof, that you can use depending on what you already proved.**

If you know that:

1. The frontier $\partial S$ of a subset $S$ is closed.
2. $ \partial A \subseteq B$ whenever $ A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is closed.

Then is it almost immediate as $\partial S \subseteq \partial S$ and $\partial S$ is closed. Therefore $\partial(\partial S) \subseteq \partial S$.

Comment: frontier = topological boundary? haven't heard that before but it is a convenient term to distinguish from manifold boundary, i guess

Comment: @BCLC According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) is seems that *frontier* is used by some authors. As I'm not a native English (that may be obvious in my answer...) I'm not able to elaborate on which situations *frontier* is used vs. *boundary*. I'm French and *frontière* is mainly used in topology... This is why I'm tempted to use *frontier* in English.

Comment: 'Some authors (for example Willard, in General Topology) use the term frontier instead of boundary in an attempt to avoid confusion with a different definition used in algebraic topology and the theory of manifolds.' --> ah thanks. convenient. frontier vs boundary. nice.

Comment: I have seen Fr($S$) for $\partial S$ on this site, and not only by the French.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any topological space. And for any $T\subseteq X$ let $T^c=X\setminus T.$ For any $S\subseteq X$ we have $$(i)\quad\partial S=\overline S \cap \overline {S^c},$$ which is closed, as it is an intersection of closed sets. So we have $$(ii)\quad \overline {\partial S}=\partial S.$$ Therefore, by replacing $S$ with $\partial S$ in $(i),$ and applying $(ii),$ we have $$\partial (\partial S)=\overline {\partial S}\cap \overline {(\partial S)^c}\subseteq$$ $$ \subseteq \overline {\partial S}=$$ $$=\partial S.$$

Comment: $\partial T\subseteq T$ for any closed set $T$.

Comment: In any topological space $X$ and any $S\subseteq X$, the sets $int(S),\,int (S^c),\,\partial S$ are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $X$.